# I try to add a property called "colorName" to UIColor, but when I assign colorName to self.view.backgroundColor, the value is NULL

Tags: objective-c, categories, uicolor

My code is

//UIColor+Theme.h

```
@interface UIColor (Theme)

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *colorName;

@end
```

//UIColor+Theme.m

```
static const void *kColorName = "colorName";

@implementation UIColor (Theme)

- (NSString *)colorName {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kColorName);
}

- (void)setColorName:(NSString *)colorName {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kColorName, colorName, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

//code in viewController.m

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.view.backgroundColor.colorName);//**print (null)**

UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
color1.colorName = @"C1";
NSLog(@"%@", color1.colorName);//**print C1**

self.view.backgroundColor = color1;
NSLog(@"%@", self.view.backgroundColor.colorName);//**print (null)**

self.view.backgroundColor.colorName = @"C1";
NSLog(@"%@", self.view.backgroundColor.colorName);//**print (null)**

UIColor *color2 = [UIColor whiteColor];
color2.colorName = @"C2"
self.view.backgroundColor = color2;
NSLog(@%@", color2.colorName);// **print C2**
NSLog(@"%@", self.view.backgroundColor.colorName);// **print C2**
```

When I use method like [UIColor whiteColor], the colorName of self.view.backgroundColor is exist.(the address of color1 and self.view.backgroundColor is same)

But when I use method like [UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:], the colorName of self.view.backgroundColor is empty.(the address of color2 and self.view.backgroundColor is different)

Maybe the problem is about deep copy about OC, because the property of self.view.backgroundColor   is (nullable, nonatomic, copy). How can I give value to self.view.backgroundColor.colorName and use the method like [UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:].

Can somebody help me, I will quite appreciate! 
Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn’t you be saying `&kColorName`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, with the exception of the predefined system colors, the `backgroundColor` of `UIView` returns a new instance every time you call it. Consider:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.2 blue:0.3 alpha:1];
NSLog(@"%p", self.view.backgroundColor);  // 0x60000034f440
NSLog(@"%p", self.view.backgroundColor);  // 0x600000325740
```

You’d expect the address for both to be the same, but they’re not.
It is behaving like a computed property for custom `UIColor` instances (perhaps generated from the backing layer’s [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410966-backgroundcolor?language=objc) property, a `CGColorRef`).

Regardless, with this sort of behavior, we can’t possibly use associated objects with the `backgroundColor` of a `UIView`.

Comment: It works with the predefined system colors because when you use them in conjunction with `backgroundColor`, you will get the same instance back. The `backgroundColor` is obviously doing some caching and/or special handling of the predefined system colors. But as it doesn’t do this with other colors, in general, it rules out the notion of associated objects in this context.